# In VSCode, 'Python: Remote Attach' fails to connect to a running Docker Container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

Good evening,

I have a container which is running and ready to connect. In VSCode I've tried to 'Attach Visual Studio Code' to open a new Dev Container, select the sources, hoping I can debug.
I'm unable to select breakpoints and the code isn't running.
Nothing happens.

I've also tried 'Python: Attach Remote'.
Nothing happens and there's no errors.

Launch.json:

```
       {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "0.0.0.0",
                "port": 3000
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                },
            ]
        }
```

Docker Compose.yml

```
 services:
      sfunc:
        image: sfunc
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        command: ["sh", "-c", "pip install debugpy -t /tmp && python /tmp/debugpy --log-to-stderr --wait-for-client --listen 127.0.0.1:3000 home/site/wwwroot/TimerTrigger/__init__.py "]
        ports:
          - 3000:3000
```

How could I troubleshoot this ?

Thank you

[image: waiting for connect]

Answer (score 0):

Those hostnames didn't work for me. Using `localhost` in the launch.json and `0.0.0.0` as the host in the `--listen` option worked.